# Break ArrayList into ArrayList of ArrayLists dynamically

Tags: java, android, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a method to breakdown an arrayList of objects into multiple arrayLists based on an attribute value of the myObj class.

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Ticket>> splitList(ArrayList<Ticket> arrayList){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Ticket>> smallLists = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        for(Ticket eachTick: Ticket.getTickets()){
            if(arrayList.get(i).getCategory().equals(eachTick.getCategory())){
                smallLists.add(...);
            }
        }


    }
    return smallLists;
}
```

If there is a better way to do what I am attempting, please advise me.

Comment: I'd split it into a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Ticket>>` first, where the key is the ticket category.  I'll post an answer in a few hours if I have time, and if nobody else posts this as an answer first.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks for the suggestion, I got the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create a list for each ticket category found in the input list? If that's the case, then I agree with Dawood ibn Kareem: use a map that looks up the proper list based on the category. Something like this:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Ticket>> splitList(ArrayList<Ticket> inputList) {
    Map<String, ArrayList<Ticket>> map = new HashMap<>();
    // your ticket categories here
    // (array used for simplicity; you should use a Set, and you should also maintain the valid categories inside your Ticket class, not here)
    String[] categories = new String[] {'a', 'b', 'c' };
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        map.put(categories[i], new ArrayList<Ticket>());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++) {
        Ticket t = inputList.get(i);
        map.get(t.getCategory()).add(t);
    }
    // Convert to list of lists
    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

Comment: Your a legend @Janus thank you for that. I must make use of Maps more often.